# How to Create single array from nested loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, nested

I just want data in single array like this. I have tried to create single final array but in property i am getting same data all the time.

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": [
        {
            "city": "City 1",
            "property": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                   
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "city": "City 2",
            "property": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "city": "City 3",
            "property": [
                {
                    "id": 18132,
                },
                {
                    "id": 17981,
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```
$custom_terms = get_terms('property_state');

    foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
        wp_reset_query();
        $args = array('post_type' => 'property',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'property_state',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
                ),
            ),
         );

         $loop = new WP_Query($args);
         if($loop->have_posts()) {
            $city_name = $custom_term->name;
            while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                $property[] =  array(
                   'id' => get_the_ID(),
                 );
            endwhile;
         }
            $final[] = array('city' =>$city_name, 'property' => $property);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you not properly initializing `$property` anywhere?

Comment: Show your expected output for clarification.